# Vim sync to remote on save

Tags: vim

I'm looking for a plugin or script that works similarly to [Sublime SFTP](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp/usage)
Basically, it should contain a configuration file and map the local and remote hierarchy.
On save to a file, it should be able to upload the changes to the remote accordingly.

Not familiar with writing Vim scripts so if that's achievable with scripts, hopefully its not too difficult to understand and modify. It should be flexible enough to be map different projects and not having to change the script each time we `cd` to a different project.

I did find the [ftpsync plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=934) but it seems quite manual with no mention of config file.

Comment: What OS do you use?

Comment: I'm using OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Vim comes wit the netrw plugin by default. It is a local/remote file explorer and you can read about it in `:h netrw`.

Basic usage looks like this:

```
:e scp://user@domain.ext/path/to/project/ " list content of remote directory
/filename<CR>                             " jump to filename
<cr>                                      " open file for editing
(editing)                                 " magic…
:w                                        " save file remotely
:Rex                                      " re-open latest file listing
rince, repeat…
```

Practically speaking, netrw works just like any other SFTP plugin/feature in any other editor/IDE: the file is downloaded, edited and saved locally and finally re-uploaded.

Netrw is quite a beast, though, I'd suggest you to read the doc carefully.

***However…***

…editing files directly on a remote server, either remotely via ssh or locally via (S)FTP, is not a very good idea. It can be slow and it's not particularily safe from a code quality point of view.

Assuming you are doing web development, a vastly better strategy is to run a development server on your own machine and only sync your files to a remote test server after you have tested everything locally.

That "syncing" part is usually handled most efficiently using a dedicated (S)FTP client GUI or CLI or, even better, a VCS like Subversion, Mercurial, Git or others.

As a web developer myself, I strongly encourage you to take the VCS route.

Comment: Hmm... am using Mercurial. So my workflow is edit local files, sync to remote for testing (cause there's some hardware not available locally), if everything's good, commit and push locally to repo. I'm not sure using Mercurial as a mean to "sync" is a good idea cause then I have to commit and push every single test.

Comment: No, that's not a good idea indeed but you didn't give the whole picture. What kind of hardware do you need that makes it impossible to test your code locally? Anyway, you should use a GUI FTP program like Transmit or YummyFTP or Interarchy… they all have the kind of "watch folder"-like feature that you want. No need to pollute your text editor.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a plugin for this purpose. It can be found here: https://github.com/hesselbom/vim-hsftp

It allows you to download or upload the current file through sftp.

It's in early stages but it has worked for my purposes and you're free to fork it or contribute if you'd like!

Answer (score 0):

a vim plugin for syncing files over sftp [can be found here](https://github.com/eshion/vim-sftp-sync)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try this plugin that I wrote: https://github.com/cosminadrianpopescu/filesync.

It works with anything that netrw supports (ftp, ssh, etc.).

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.